# Similar to Scala macro in Java

Tags: java, scala, java-8

Anybody know if in Java there´s something like `Scala macro` to interact with the javac in compilation time. `Reflection` it´s quite powerful, but only works on runtime.

Comment: A quick search on Google comes up with a definitive *NO*. Did your search fail?

Comment: I did not find anything. But it's hard to believe that java don't offer a similar feature being so powerful to create DSLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java there are no macros like in Scala but there is kind of macros like in C++.

[Can I have macros in Java source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525059/can-i-have-macros-in-java-source-files)

[Macros in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914804/macros-in-java)

[Using scala macro from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078538/using-scala-macro-from-java)

There are also

- Manifold http://manifold.systems/ https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold
- Spoon https://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/ https://github.com/INRIA/spoon
- Joern https://joern.io/ https://github.com/joernio/joern
- compile-time annotation processing [Is there a way to create custom annotations in Scala and write a custom annotation processor to verify the annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443039/is-there-a-way-to-create-custom-annotations-in-scala-and-write-a-custom-annotati)
- Lombok https://projectlombok.org/ https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok